# Removing Multi-driver nets

Tags: verilog, fpga

I have a static array in verilog and I'm reading a value and trying to find the index of that value in the array.

For this I've done

```
array[0:200] = {32h'14151,...};
reg[8:0] val_idx = 511;
reg[31:0] val; 
generate begin: hash
for(genvar i = 0 ; i < 200; i = i + 1) begin: hash_loop
   always@ (posedge clk) begin
     case(value)
     array[i]:
       val_idx <= i;
     endcase
   end  
end
end endgenerate
```

However when I try to synthesise it using Vivado I get `Multiple Driver Nets` 200 times and it bails. What is the correct way to do this? I'm new to verilog so apologies if the question is stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generate for-loop reproduces the code. Thus what you are writing gets expanded to:

```
   always@ (posedge clk) begin
   case(value)
   array[0]:
     val_idx <= 0;
   endcase
 end  

 always@ (posedge clk) begin
   case(value)
   array[1]:
     val_idx <= 1;
   endcase
 end  

etc.
```

From that you can see that val_idx is driven from two *always* statements.

You might think that the statements are independent but they are not. 
That is because you did not specify an default thus the rule is that in that case val_id should remain unchanged.

Remove the genvar and use a normal for-loop inside the clocked section.

Notes:

*reg[8:0] val_idx = 511;* Does not work the way you probably think it does!
use *val_idx <= 511;* as first statement in the 'always' section.

Your piece of code will expand into a huge amount of logic. You get 200 eight-bit comparators which will get partly optimized. There is a reason why associative memories are done as a dedicated piece of logic.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm actually trying to implement rudimentary hash table only, is there a better way to do it? I don't have to insert anything i.e. my entires are static, just need to get the indexes.

Comment: Not if you want to find the index in one clock cycle. I would say, try to avoid the whole lookup but I don't know what your are trying to achieve. Oh and I noticed an error in my text: they are 32-bit compares. Also beware: your "array" is only 201 bits long.